# Are these UV-C tubes meant to be run only on pure AC ballast?

Tags: light, uv, tube, electronic-ballast

I’ve this portable small T5 4W UV-A 300-400nm black light tube lamp with me. I’m trying to see if it’s possible to use a 4W UV-C lamp in the same fixture. But I noticed that the lamp has the violet glow only to one side which makes me think the supply is pulsed DC likely. But I noticed that the tube has started to darken on both filament ends as shown in picture.

Anyone has any idea what might be causing this or is this tube Int meant to be run on an AC type ballast. 
[image: Blackening at filaments]

[image]

Comment: OSRAM Puritec lamps run on AC ballasts.

Comment: XY problem. Darkening around the filaments are normal on all fluorescent tubes from the turngsten evaporating and depositing on the tube.

Answer (score 3):

These fluro torches typically have very basic inverters in them. the ones I've owned didn't even use the heaters instead treating the tube as cold-cathode and igniting it  by breakdown. I don't think that's very good for the tube.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLaD11LITbQ

Answer (score 2):

That stuff you're saying about AC ballast and pulsed DC doesn't make any sense.  Either a ballast supports a bulb type or it doesn't.  Each ballast has a list of types they support.  You're looking for a different color temperature (UV-C vs UV-A): That's not a type; most types are offered in several color temperatures.

That thing is a plain old fluorescent tube.  *Remember, fluorescent tubes make UV naturally, and that UV light is (normally) converted into visible light by the **phosphors** coating the tube*. So making UV isn't a particularly big detour for a fluorescent tube. That's why they're still preferred even in the LED age.

Note the rings near the ends of the tube, above the preheating coils.  That is spallation, which indicates the tube is at the end of its life.  Fluorescent tubes don't "pop" like Edison bulbs, their strike voltage rises higher and higher (until the ballast can't strike them) whilst their light performance decline - stuff like you see there.

It's not magic woo-woo pulsed DC, the bulb is just worn out. Simple as that.

One thing that wears out tubes VERY quickly is **placing them on an incompatible ballast**, e.g. putting an F32T8 tube on an F40T12 ballast.

The ballast, or the fixture itself, will identify specific types of fluorescent tube that it is compatible with.  `T5 4W UV-A 300-400nm` is not a tube type identifier.  `4W UV-C` is also not a tube type identifier.   Both seem to be saying a lot about color temperature, which is fine, but that's not a tube type.

I'm really on my back foot here because 1000bulbs.com is down, but I'm guessing that fixture takes an F4T5 of any color temperature you want.

Wild guessing here, I have a feeling that's a G4T5 tube, which I suspect is not listed on the ballast's list of supported tube types.

Answer (score 2):

I use identical hand lamps for exactly the same thing, removing the black-light tube and putting a 4W "germicidal" tube in its place. Note that such tubes give off UVC which is harmful to the eyes and skin. And the more energetic UVC portion produces ozone which you can smell and is irritating after a while. I'm not particularly interested in the germicidal properties, I just like making rocks fluoresce! So I add a filter to the lamp. It costs more than the lamp itself.

So, to the matter in hand, the glow pattern indicates a "DC" drive. Most of the UV radiation comes from the blue-green "positive column". A quick look through a diffraction grating shows a blue line (there's also a very near ultraviolet line that a camera will pick up but your eyes don't), a green line and a yellow line (it's actually two). There is very little red, if any. The glow round the cathode is usually too fuzzy to make out any further structure as described in the textbooks but in any case it is rather variable and typically includes a purple blob - there is more going on in the gas here than in the positive column and there is definitey some red in the light.

The actual voltage is not really DC but is likely to be a very asymmetrical waveform and only sufficient to drive the tube in one direction - as you say, pulsed. This in itself is not particularly harmful to the tube. In fact you will probably find there is less than 2W taken from the battery so the tube is under-run.

And that is the problem. These tubes are designed to run with the cathodes at a dull red heat. This allows thermionic emission of electrons. When the cathode is cold, electrons are emitted via a completely different process, namely through bombardment with positively charged ions. This is damaging to the cathode and causes an erosion of the material called sputtering, which causes the ends of the tube to blacken. Not only does this block light, it also wears out the cathode and, to add insult to injury, it even traps some of the rarified gas in the tube, making it harder to strike.

Ideally, cathodes are pre-heated so there is very little damage done at start-up, but simple (cheap) inverters do not bother and some tube manufacturers even sanction a cold start - with the caveat that tube life will be impaired. What you do not want, however, is for the tube to run continuously in this condition. The ends will blacken as you watch. So the solution is to make sure the tube is run at adequate power to keep the cathode(s) hot. Interestingly, this heat is provided by the incoming ions, but they are neutralised and stopped before they hit the cathode. The hot gas layer then heats the cathode. Plus, of course, there is some resistive heating due to the current.

But this all fails when the battery is getting flat. Without enough power to heat the cathode, thermionic emission is lost and the cathode reverts to self-destruct mode.

The answer is to use fresh batteries or hook up a 5-6v power supply. Don't push things by giving it say 9v to try to get a bit more light. The tube will love it but the inverter has very little design margin and may die at just 7v.

By the way, the amount of blackening you had in the picture is very minimal. You can certainly use it as long as it quickly gets going. The picture of the discharge is completely normal.